# Symfony & Doctrine getting a joined query to work

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I've got an SQL query that returns all the rows in one table (country) which have a related entry in another table (ducks) but I'm struggling to turn this into DQL. This is a standard one-many relationship as each country can have multiple ducks, I believe it is all set up correctly as I can return ducks within a country and return the country a  duck is in using standard code.

The working query is:

```
SELECT c.* FROM country c 
INNER JOIN ducks d 
ON c.id = d.country_id 
GROUP BY c.country 
ORDER BY c.country ASC
```

I've tried converting this to:

```
SELECT c FROM WfukDuckBundle:Country c 
INNER JOIN WfukDuckBundle:Ducks d 
ON c.id = d.country_id 
GROUP BY c.country 
ORDER BY c.country ASC
```

which produces the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 79 near 'd ON': Error: Identification Variable 
WfukDuckBundle:Ducks used in join path expression but was not defined before.
```

I'm quite new to Symfony/Doctrine so I suspect it's probably something obvious!

I'm using Symfony 2.0.11 with doctrine

Update:
I've Also tried:

```
SELECT c FROM WfukDuckBundle:Country c 
INNER JOIN c.ducks d 
ON c.id = d.country_id 
GROUP BY c.country 
ORDER BY c.country ASC
```

where 'ducks' is defined in the Country class as:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ducks", mappedBy="country")
 */
protected $ducks;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->ducks = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

the definition for country in the ducks class is:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="ducks")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $country;
```

Comment: The error seems to tell that the entity WfukDuckBundle:Ducks is not defined in the EntityManager.. The exception is thrown from Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php, method: JoinAssociationPathExpression (l. 930) : you can start debugging from there.

Comment: And your ON clause doesn't look DQL compatible : "ON c.id = d.country"

Comment: Thanks, you're right the JOIN was wrong, there was no need for the ON clause, slowly getting the hang of Doctrine. For anyone else the query should have been: `SELECT c FROM WfukDuckBundle:Country c 
       INNER JOIN c.ducks d 
       GROUP BY c.country 
       ORDER BY c.country ASC`

Comment: @Al Please post your solution as the answer and mark it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do yourself a favour and use the query builder. Easier to read and update and reuse your queries

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Prefix\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class SomeRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function countryDucks()
    {
        // $em is the entity manager
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb
            ->select('country', 'duck')
            ->from('WfukDuckBundle:Country', 'country')
            ->innerJoin('country.ducks', 'duck')
            ->groupBy('country.country')
            ->orderBy('country.country', 'ASC')
        ;

        $query = $qb->getQuery();

        // Potential Hydration Modes
        // --------------------------------
        // Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT
        // Will give you an array of your object entities
        // --------------------------------
        // Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY 
        // Will give you an array mimicking 
        // your object graph 
        // --------------------------------

        return $query->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems a much neater way of handling it. I tried the code above and it worked if I removed the `Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY`. I'm quite new to doctrine and I'm not entirely sure what this does, it still seems to return the results I'd expect with just getResult().

Comment: Check. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#hydration-modes Hydration modes determine the kind of result you get back...generally you want to hydrate objects for single results. When returning large sets you will get better performance from hydrating an array